# Python: How to find most frequent combination of elements?

Tags: python, pandas, combinations

A machine provides fault codes which are provided in a pandas dataframe. `id` identifies the machine, `code` is the fault code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4],
    "code": [1,2,5,8,9,2,3,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
})
```

[image]

Reading example: Machine 1 generated 5 codes: 1,2,5,8 and 9.

I want to find out which code combinations are most frequent across all machines. The result for the example would be something like `[2]`(3x), `[2,5]`(3x), `[3,5]`(2x) and so on.

How can I achive this? As there is a lot of data, I'm looking for a efficient solution.

Here are two other ways to represent the data (in case that makes the calculation easier):

```
pd.crosstab(df.id, df.code)
```

[image]

```
df.groupby("id")["code"].apply(list)
```

[image]

Comment: Does ordering matter? is `[2, 5]` different than `[5,2]`?

Comment: Ordering does not matter; `[2,5]` equals `[5,2]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use custom function `all_subsets`, then flatten values by [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and last use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898031
#only converted to list and removed empty tuples by range(1,...
def all_subsets(ss):
    return list(chain(*map(lambda x: combinations(ss, x), range(1, len(ss)+1))))

s = df.groupby('id')['code'].apply(all_subsets).explode().value_counts()
print (s)
(2,)            3
(2, 5)          3
(5,)            3
(1, 2)          2
(3, 6)          2
               ..
(1, 5, 8)       1
(9,)            1
(1, 3, 4, 6)    1
(5, 8, 9)       1
(4, 6)          1
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Would you mind elaborating a bit on your code?

Comment: @Julian - I create all possible combinations for group for list of tuples, so added `explode` for list of tuples for possible count it by `value_counts`